# The convolution of an integrable function with a $p$-integrable function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $\Sigma$ denote the set of Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $1<p\leq \infty$, $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},\Sigma,m)$, and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R},\Sigma,m)$. Show that 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)g(x-y)\mathrm{d}m(y)$$ exists for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I can only assume that they mean that the above integral is finite almost everywhere. So, I must show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(y)g(x-y)|\mathrm{d}m(y)<\infty$$

For the case $p=\infty$, I think if I can prove $|g(x)|\leq ||g||_{\infty}$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then I'll be done. Is this the most straightforward approach? Or is this intermediate result actually harder than trying the proof directly?

When $p< \infty$, I used the Fubini-Tonelli theorem to reduce the problem to showing that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|\mathrm{d}m \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|^p\mathrm{d}m$$ although again, this seems like it may be a roundabout way that is harder than a direct proof. Unfortunately, nothing else is jumping at me.

Comment: "the Lebesgue integral of any measurable function exists (even though it may be infinite)," No, that's not true. Unless you assume something more, like the function is positive

Comment: Also, your last inequality is not true, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume WLOG $f,g$ are nonnegative. Claim:

$$ \int f(y)(g(x-y))^p\, dy < \infty$$

for a.e. x. Proof: If we integrate the left side with respect ot $x,$ we can switch the order of integration to get, by Tonelli, $(\int f)(\int g^p)< \infty.$ The claim follows.

So now write $g = g_1 +g_2,$ where $g_1= g\chi_{\{g\le 1\}}, g_2= g\chi_{\{g> 1\}}.$ We know $ \int f(y)g_1(x-y)\,dy < \infty$ for every $x.$ As for $g_2,$ note that $g_2 \le g_2^p.$ So

$$\int f(y)g_2(x-y)\,dy \le \int f(y)[g_2(x-y)]^p\,dy$$

and the latter is finite a.e. by the claim above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how we know $\int f(y)g_1(x-y)dy < \infty$?

Comment: that's $L^1$ convolved w. $L^\infty$

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not following you. Are you saying that for $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^{\infty}$, $f*g\in L^1$ as well? If so then I haven't seen this result before, so I probably shouldn't make use of it

Comment: No, I'm saying if $f\in L^1, g \in L^\infty \implies fg\in L^1,$ which is obvious

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f \in L^1$ and $g \in L^p$, then $f*g(x)$ exists for almost every $x$, $f * g \in L^p$ and moreover, $\|f*g\|_p\leq\|f\|_1\|g\|_p$.

This follows directly from Minkowski's integral inequality ([Theorem 1.4](http://www.math.duke.edu/~wka/math204/conv.12.4.pdf)). In fact,
$$
\|f*g\|_p = \left\|\int f(y)g(\cdot-y)\,dy\right\|_p \leq \int \left|f(y)\right|\|\tau_y g\|_p \,dy = \|f\|_1\|g\|_p,
$$
using the translation invariance of the $L^p$ norm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to prove that $f*g$ exists almost everywhere without the integral form of Minkowski's inequality?